# SQL List and Sum together

Tags: sql, sapb1

I have a SQL query in SAP B1 that lists sales for the week. I also have a query that makes a Sum of those same sales. How do I combine the queries so that the result is all the rows of sales with the sum shown as a row below those rows?

SQL List query-

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], 
       T1.[CardName], T1.[CardFName], T0.[DocTotalSy] AS Total 
  FROM ORDR T0 
  INNER JOIN OCRD T1 
  ON    T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
  WHERE T0.[DocDate] > (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE()), 101))
```

SQL Sum query-

```
SELECT SUM (T0.[DocTotalSy]) AS Total 
  FROM ORDR T0  
  INNER JOIN OCRD T1 
  ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
  WHERE T0.[DocDate] > (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE()), 101))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `group by with rollup` statement (described [here](http://help.sap.com/hana/html/sql_select.html)):

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T1.[CardName], T1.[CardFName], sum(T0.[DocTotalSy]) AS Total
FROM ORDR T0 INNER JOIN
     OCRD T1
     ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
WHERE T0.[DocDate] > (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE()), 101))
group by T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T1.[CardName], T1.[CardFName] with rollup
```

However, this might not be exactly what you want.  I can see that either `rollup` or `grouping sets` will work for your query, but it is hard to tell exactly what will produce what you want.  Sample results are always helpful for communicating effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the sum in the existing first query and then use group by:

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T1.[CardName], T1.[CardFName], T0.[DocTotalSy] AS Total, sum(T0.[DocTotalSy]) AS SumTotal
FROM ORDR T0 INNER JOIN
     OCRD T1
     ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
WHERE T0.[DocDate] > (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE()), 101))
group by T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T1.[CardName], T1.[CardFName]
```

Comment: If there are more than one results with same `T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T1.[CardName], T1.[CardFName]`, they would be merged into one result.